# Filesystem Label Rename

Tags: btrfs

I'm getting a strange error quark 11 on renaming my filesystems on Ubuntu 12.10 64. I'm sure 100% I've already done it in the past without issues using the disk utility. Maybe some recent upgrade or I don't know what, but now I get an error:

> Don't know how to change label on device of type filesystem:btrfs (udisks-error-quark, 11))

It's not critical to me, but you may find it useful for the records. I've not been able to find anything around about this quark 11 error.

Answer (score 39):

I've seen this with BtrFS volumes.  The Disks utility doesn't appear to know how to handle them yet.

From a command line, use:

```
sudo btrfs filesystem label <mountpoint> <newlabel>
```

if the filesystem is mounted.

Else, if unmounted, use:

```
sudo btrfs filesystem label <device> <newlabel>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of the reputation requirements I cannot post this as a comment, but calling `btrfs system label` will not notify the rest of the system so despite `btrfs filesystem show` displaying the new label, tools like `lsblk` require a `udevadm trigger` call to update.

btrfs's documentation for good measure - https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/UseCases#How_do_I_label_a_filesystem.3F